# Adding elements from a random list to another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple and silly game of cards. For that, I created 4 different classes:

Card:

```
class card():

    def __init__(self, name, power) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.power = power

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Card: {self.name}\nPower: {self.power}\n'
```

Deck:

```
class deck():
    cards = []
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def add_card_to_deck(self,card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        s = 'Cards:'
        for c in self.cards:
            s+=str(c)

        return s
```

Player:

```
from deck import *

class player():
    
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.deck = deck()


    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Player:{self.name}\n'

    def print_cards(self):
        st = f'{self.name} cards:\n'
        for c in self.deck.cards:
            st += str(c)
        
        return st
```

Game logic:

```
from card import *
from deck import *
from player import *
import random



card_one = card("Ghost", 700)
card_two = card('Wizard of Oz', 950)
card_three = card('Hunter', 1000)
card_four = card('Jason', 600)
card_five = card('Creepy clown', 700)
card_six = card('dwarf', 690)

cards_list = [card_five, card_four, card_one, card_three, card_two, card_six]


def start_game():
    # gets the names of the two players
    first_player_name= input('First player\'s name: ')
    first_player = player(first_player_name)
    second_player_name = input('Second player\'s name: ')
    second_player = player(second_player_name)
    # gives random cards to the players
    give_cards_to_decks(first_player, second_player)
    #choosing a card
    # choose_card(player_on=second_player)
    


def give_cards_to_decks(player_one, player_two):

    
    random.shuffle(cards_list)
    
    for index in range(6):
        if index<3:
            print(' -- adding to player one --')
            player_one.deck.add_card_to_deck(cards_list[index])
            print(cards_list[index])
        else:
            print(' -- adding to player two --')
            player_two.deck.add_card_to_deck(cards_list[index])
            print(cards_list[index])

    print('player one deck cards')
    print(player_one.deck)
    print('player two deck cards')
    print(player_two.deck)



def choose_card(player_on):
    print(' ----- testing -----')
    print(player_on.print_cards())

def win_play():
    pass
```

When I run the `give_cards_to_decks()` function, instead of adding only three elements to each player's deck, it adds all 6 elements.

```
First player's name: m
Second player's name: j
 -- adding to player one --
Card: Wizard of Oz
Power: 950

 -- adding to player one --
Card: dwarf
Power: 690

 -- adding to player one --
Card: Jason
Power: 600

 -- adding to player two --
Card: Creepy clown
Power: 700

 -- adding to player two --
Card: Ghost
Power: 700

 -- adding to player two --
Card: Hunter
Power: 1000

player one deck cards
Cards:Card: Wizard of Oz
Power: 950
Card: dwarf
Power: 690
Card: Jason
Power: 600
Card: Creepy clown
Power: 700
Card: Ghost
Power: 700
Card: Hunter
Power: 1000

player two deck cards
Cards:Card: Wizard of Oz
Power: 950
Card: dwarf
Power: 690
Card: Jason
Power: 600
Card: Creepy clown
Power: 700
Card: Ghost
Power: 700
Card: Hunter
Power: 1000
```

Does anyone have any idea of what might be causing this outcome? When I print each card being added to the deck, it prints the cards individually, but the result is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

`cards` is a class-level variable of the `Deck` class. This state is shared across *all* instances of Deck. So when you're appending to both player's decks, you're appending to the same list.

The deck class should look like the following. Notice that the `cards` is now instance-level, rather than class-level:

```py
class deck():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.cards = []

    def add_card_to_deck(self,card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        s = 'Cards:'
        for c in self.cards:
            s+=str(c)

        return s
```